# Xcode orientation property does not return current orientation

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, orientation, hide

I want to disable a button myButton when the device is rotated to the right. I set up an if block to hide the button when rotated, but the device doesn't recognize that it has been rotated. My NSLog statement displays false when I run the simulation and rotate the simulator. Why is it doing this?

```c
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
NSLog(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft?@"true":@"false");

if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]  == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
   [myButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
{
     [myButton setHidden:YES];
}

return interfaceOrientation;
}
```

best of luck....

Comment: So I tested my view with: NSLog(UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)?@"true":@"false");
and I keep on getting false. What would cause an invalid orientation?